# Tooltip "steals" binded value from its source in another window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window, tabcontrol

I have pretty untypical problem. I'm using two windows - `MainView` with `TabControl` and `Chooser` with `Listbox` - to choose active `TabItem`. When tooltip in listbox item  binded with header in `Chooser` is showing, the same header disappears from `TabControl`, leaving empty tab. Whatsmore - the same binding connected with text in textbox doesn't cause such a reaction.

`Chooser`:

```
public class Chooser : Window
{
    MainView parent;

    public PlanChooser(MainView start, ItemCollection list)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listbox.ItemsSource = list;
        parent = start;
    }
}
```

`Chooser` initialization from MainView:

```
Chooser chooseTab = new Chooser (this, tabControlTest.Items);
chooseTab.Show();
```

Style from Chooser.xaml

```
 <Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="bigIcons">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl MouseDoubleClick="ContentControl_MouseDoubleClick">
                    <StackPanel ToolTip="{Binding Header, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                        <Image Source="" 
                               Width="40" Height="40">
                        </Image>
                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" 
                         TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Width="44" 
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

...and `TabControl` from `MainView`:

```
 <TabControl Name="tabControlTest" Background="Transparent"/>
```

Does anyone know how to solve it or had a similar problem?

Comment: Maybe change the mode in your tool tip's binding, eg. `ToolTip="{Binding Header}"`.

Comment: I already changed it from this into oneway and tried other binding modes, thx for idea :)